# Git attributes affecting submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible that mine `.gitattributes` file affects submodule?

I'm interested in specifying filter and smudge/clean, so it would be applied during checkouts in submodule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: if you want to define a content filter driver (smudge/clean script) applied during the checkout of a submodule, it needs to be defined in a `.gitattributes` stored within the submodule repo.

BUT: if you don't want to add a `.gitattributes` to the submodule repo (because, for instance, you don't own that repo, you are only including it and want to apply a filter which makes sense in your context), what you can do is:

- initialize the submodule (`git submodule init` or even `git submodule update --init`):
  That will create in your parent repo a `.git/modules/yourSubmodule` folder
- copy in `.git/modules/yourSubmodule/info/attributes` the attributes you want to declare for certain files (here, fore instance, all ruby files)

  ```
  *.rb filter=yourFilter
  ```

**That will play the role of the `.gitattributes` (still valid only for the submodule, but defined and stored in your `parent_repo/.git/modules/`)**
That way, you can define attributes for a submodule without having to add a `.gitattributes` within the submodule repo itself.

It isn't exactly a '`.gitattributes`' of your parent repo: it is something you add after initializing a submodule, within the `.git/modules` folder of your parent repo.
You can store the content of that "gitattributes" as a regular file in your parent repo, but you will have to write a script able to initialize submodule and copy that file as a `.git/modules/yourSubmodule/info/attributes` file.
I have done so in my project: see this [installation script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/fcee557a4c5787a1add4dfcf22a03b9e35c9bb2f/gitlab/install_or_update_gitlab.sh.tpl#L26-L32) as an example.

- modify `.git/modules/yourSubmodule/config` in order to declare a smudge or clean filter referencing that script.

  ```
  [filter "yourFiler"]
      smudge= yourScript1 %f
      clean = yourScript2 %f
  ```

Then, providing you did already update your submodule (`git submodule update`), running a

```
cd parentRepo/yourSubmodule
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

That will trigger your filter scripts for that submodule